# Класс, который отправляет команду на печать чека на принтер, не работает в проекте для android (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: xamarin.forms

Мы написали приложения для Android и iOS на Xamarin forms. В программе можно отправляет команду на печать чека на принтер. При отладке приложения на Android-смартфоне принтер выдает чек, но после выпуска приложения (подготовка .apk) и его установки на Android-устройстве не работает функция выдачи чека.

```
public async Task TestPrinter(string ip, int port)
    {
        await Print(LineHelper.GetReStringedLineBytes("IP: " + AppSettings.PrinterIP + " Port: " + AppSettings.PrinterPort).ToArray(), ip, port);
    }
    public void PrintEpson(byte[] data, string ip = null, int port = 0)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip) || port == 0)
        {
            ip = AppSettings.PrinterIP;
            port = AppSettings.PrinterPort;
        }
        var printer = new NetworkPrinter(ipAddress: ip, port: port, reconnectOnTimeout: true);
      
        int resourceId = Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.GetIdentifier("logocheck", "drawable", "com.companyname.uposshop");
        var icon = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Android.App.Application.Context.Resources, resourceId);

        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        icon.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 50, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.ToArray();

        var e = new EPSON();
        printer.Write(
          ByteSplicer.Combine(
              e.CenterAlign(),
            e.PrintImage(byteArray, true, true, 400, 3),
            e.LeftAlign(),
            e.PrintLine(" ")
            )) ; 
        printer.Write(AddCut(data));
    }
```

Дайте пожалуйста рекомендации по решению проблемы.